# Sprache für automatische Übersetzung ins Deutsche

Tags: translation

Ich vergleiche gern die unterschiedlichen Sprachen eines Lemmas in der Wikipedia. Diese sind längst nicht immer gleich gut gepflegt. Manchmal finden sich in einzelnen anderen Sprachen interessante Details. Die meisten anderen Artikel kann ich nur dank der automatischen Übersetzung lesen, da ich die Sprachen nicht spreche. Darum frage ich mich nun,

*Welche Sprachen eignen sich besonders gut, um sie automatisiert ins Deutsche zu übersetzen?*

Answer (score 2):

Niederländisch! Die beiden Sprachen sind sich sehr ähnlich, es ist fast möglich, Texte Wort für Wort zu übersetzen, mit Ausnahme einiger Besonderheiten, die sich jedoch gut berücksichtigen lassen.

Wer die eine Sprache kann, hat meist wenig Probleme, die andere zumindest zu verstehen; der Satzbau ist fast gleich, und der Klang bzw. die Aussprache mancher Wörter ähneln sich sehr (obwohl das für einen automatischen Übersetzer wohl weniger relevant ist).

Comment: Diese Antwort liefert zwar ein scheinbar plausibles Argument (Ähnlichkeit) mit, es bleibt aber spekulativ. Eventuell sind ja die [falschen Freunde](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falscher_Freund#Niederl.C3.A4ndische_falsche_Freunde) gerade zwischen dem Niederländischen und dem Deutschen ein besonderes Übersetzungshemmnis!

Comment: definitiv nicht, da der automatische übersetzer nicht "versteht" und "denkt" wie jemand, der als deutscher einen niederländer sprechen hört. da wird das niederländische wort eingelesen, übersetzt, grammatikalisch angepasst und fertig. das niederländische wort "bellen" zum beispiel wird nicht für das deutsche wort "bellen" gehalten werden, sondern schlichtweg übersetzt ("klingeln"), genauso wie jedes andere wort auch. :)

Comment: Schon klar... bloß kann die maschinelle Übersetzung nur das umsetzen, was zuvor programmiert wurde... von Menschen... und diese machen wiederum menschliche Fehler. Bin aber mit den Geheimnissen der Computerlinguistik zu wenig vertraut...

Comment: da hast du recht, ich gind davon aus, dass der programmierer "perfekt" übersetzt, und die schwierigkeit in der automatischen übersetzung liegt. falsche freunde machen da dann kein problem mehr, eher worte mit verschiedenen übersetzungen.

Comment: Wie sieht es denn vergleichsweise mit Plattdeutsch aus? nds.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:H%C3%B6%C3%B6ftsiet

Comment: Luxemburgisch (Letzeburgesch) ist vielleicht naher an Hochdeutsch als Niederländisch?

Answer (score 1):

Die Sprachen, bei denen der größte Aufwand getrieben wurde, einen Übersetzer zu entwickeln. Also Englisch.

Answer (score 0):

You need

1. a linguistically similar language (with similar structure, morpho-syntactic and semantic) which is one of the West Germanic languages: Dutch or English
2. a good translation robot

Also search the internet for "machine translation".

Comment: Wie sieht es denn vergleichsweise mit Plattdeutsch aus? http://nds.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:H%C3%B6%C3%B6ftsiet

Comment: @Toscho: Dafür sieht's bei Wikipedia wahrscheinlich trübe aus

Answer (score 0):

Statt Ähnlichkeit konnte man auch für Regularität und damit einfache (und zuverlässiger) Parsing gehen. Niederländisch ist, wie, Deutsch komplex. Ja, man kann mechanisch Wort-fuer-wort übersetzen, aber der Computer versteht es nicht wirklich, und komplexere Transformationen sind schwieriger.

Von dieser Ansichtpunkt aus (begriff-volles Parsen am wichtigsten, Deutsch Generation klappt schon)  wurden denn eher Spanisch oder Esperanto logischer als Eingangssprachen sein.

Answer (score -2):

Artikel auf **russisch** liefern mit Google Chromes automatischer Übersetzung (also Google Translate) gut lesbare Seiten.

Comment: Ich setze mal ein -1, da diese Antwort rein subjektiv und durch nichts belegt ist, hoffe aber darauf, dass ich dies im Anschluss an eine Erweiterung und Verbesserung zurückziehen kann. Verbesserungsmöglichkeiten wären z.B. ein Hinweis auf eine Forschungsarbeit, die sich der Frage bereits angenommen hat und mit quantitativen Ergebnissen aufwarten kann.

Comment: Okay, akzeptiert. Aber alte Bewertungen können nicht zurück gezogen werden. Und eine rein subjektive und nicht wissenschaftlich belegte Antwort kann anderen Nutzern bereits eine Hilfe sein.

Comment: Downvotes können, soweit ich weiß, rückgängig gemacht werden, sobald die Antwort überarbeitet wurde. Selbstverständlich muss nicht jede Antwort wissenschaftlich belegt werden! Aber ein bisschen mehr als bloße Meinung ohne argumentative und/oder empirische Unterfütterung darf es schon sein.

Comment: Man kann votes definitiv zuruecknehmen. [Hier](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139950) sind die Bedingungen.

Comment: Eine mögliche Vertiefung: vor Jahren hat mir jemand "vom Fach" (computational linguistics) erklärt, Russisch sei im Kalten Krieg mit großem Abstand die am gründlichsten analysierte Quellsprache gewesen. Das Pentagon steckte damals Unsummen in die Forschung, um jeden sowjetischen Aufsatz sofort ins Englische übersetzen zu können. Wenn -- großes Wenn! -- Google Translate auf diesem Bestand aufbaut und zweites Wenn, mit einer Art Interlingua zwischen allen Sprachpaaren arbeitet, dann wäre es nicht nur plausibel sondern fast schon zwangsläufig, dass GT's Ergebnisse aus dem RU gut sein sollen.

Comment: Diese Antwort wäre die richtige gewesen, wenn es in der Frage nicht um "Automatisierte" Übersetzungen ginge, denn Russisch ist sehr detailreich und Deutsch passt da sehr gut mit rein, jedoch ist genau dies das Problem von automatischen Übersetzungsprogrammen, diese schaffen es nicht die Intelligenz beider Sprachen korrekt zu übersetzen, schon garnicht der Google Übersetzer der sich höchstens für Englisch zu Englisch Übersetzungen eignet :)